# mySQL - subquery with multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

**Table *Matches***

```
id | TeamA    | TeamB
--------------
1  | Barça    | Madrid
2  | Valencia | Depotivo
```

**Table *Payments***

```
idMatch | User  | Quantity
---------------------------
1       | Me    | 50
2       | Me    | 100
```

Then in one query I want to get TeamA, TeamB, User and Quantity if they have same id.

I've tried this but **it fails**.

```
SELECT TeamA, TeamB FROM Matches WHERE id IN (SELECT idMatch, TeamA, TeamB FROM Payments)
```

Comment: please describe more as this is not clear your requirement.

Comment: How would your desired output look, given the example above?

Comment: please post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT TeamA, TeamB ,User  , Quantity FROM Matches m
 inner join Payments p
 on p.idMatch = m.id
 WHERE id IN 
 (SELECT idMatch FROM Payments)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aae60/4)

Answer (score 2):

you can use joins

```
select Matches.TeamA,Matches.TeamB,Payments.User,Payments.Quantity from Matches,Payments where Matches.id=Payments.idMatch
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT payments.user,
    payments.quantity
FROM
     Payments
     INNER JOIN Matches ON (Matches.id = Payments.idMatch);
```

Answer (score 1):

IN() should contain a list of values like `IN('red','green','blue')` or `IN(1,3,53)`. SELECT is fine, but it has to return a single field. This would work.

```
SELECT TeamA, TeamB FROM Matches
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT idMatch FROM Payments
)
```

However it looks like you want to achieve something you need JOIN or GROUP BY for.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT 
    TeamA, 
    TeamB,
    payments.user,
    payments.quantity
FROM 
    matches
    JOIN payments ON ( matches.id = payments.matchid )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.TeamA,m.TeamB,p.`User`,p.Quantity from matches m INNER join
payments p where p.idMatch=m.id
```